# Spring Cloud Gateway token relay with Keycloak resource owner password credentials grant

Tags: keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-oauth2

Our application has it's own login/signup and user management portal. We don't want to redirect the user to keycloak login page, due to which authorization code grant flow is out of the picture. I am trying to find a way to use spring cloud gateway's TokenRelay filter with password grant.

Comment: I'm also interested how this issue can be fixed. Can you share did you managed to solve the issue?